# jQuery check if start_date is bigger than end_date

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following problem.

I get a start_date and end_date from my HTML form, both dates are valid and are entered/selected by a bootstrap date picker.

An example of the dates are as follows

```
start_date = 15-06-2016
end_date = 14-06-2016
```

I have the following code to check if the start date is large than the end date:

```
if (Date.parse(start_date) > Date.parse(end_date))
{
    error = true;
    console.log('start date is greater than end date');
}
else
{
    console.log('start date is smaller than end date');
}
```

start date is bigger than the end date, but in my validation, is always logs "start date is smaller than end date"

I also tried the following in my conditional statement, but still get the same results:

```
if (new Date(start_date) > new Date(end_date))
if (start.Date > date.Date)
```

if I switch the ">" with "<", I still get the same results. The statement always does the else statement.

I think the conversion from string to date might be the problem.

Thanks in advance

Comment: The date formats you have cannot be read correctly by the `Date()` constructor (example here: https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/4q7pdt3r/). You need to change them to `mm/dd/yyyy` format first.

Comment: Are `start_date` and `end_date` variables numbers or strings?

Comment: they are string values that I am trying to convert to time

Comment: thanx @Rory, will try to change the format and let you know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `String.prototype.split()`, `Array.prototype.reverse()`, `Array.prototype.join()`, `new Date()`, `.getTime()`

```js
var start_date = "15-06-2016"
, end_date = "14-06-2016";

function getTime(d) {
  return new Date(d.split("-").reverse().join("-")).getTime()
}

console.log(getTime(start_date) > getTime(end_date))
```

Comment: this is the shortest code and the first one to work, thanx!

Answer (score 3):

This date format is not recognised by [Date.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse).

```js
console.log(Date.parse('15-06-2016'));
```

If you want it to be recognised you need to use the `mm/dd/yyyy` format or the `yyyy-mm-dd` format.

```js
console.log(Date.parse('06/15/2016'));
```

If you want to use custom format, you will have to implement your own your parser (e.g. by [splitting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) on `'-'`) or use a library such as [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/).

```js
console.log(moment("06-15-2016", "MM-DD-YYYY"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.13.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
start_date = 15-06-2016
end_date = 14-06-2016
```

Use

```
var start_date = new Date('15-06-2016');
var end_date = new Date('14-06-2016');
```

Rest of your code remains same.

Comment: the dates as listed in the top of your answer are just examples I added, the actual dates are received from the form, I tried `if (new Date(start_date) > new Date(end_date))`, but got the same results

Answer (score 0):

First try to convert your date format to Standard JavaScript Date format like `YYYY-MM-DD` and then you can parse it to `Date` object. Once you done with it, then you can do the required comparison like below:

Standard date formats can be found at this link: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_date_formats.asp

```js
var start_date = '15-06-2016';
var end_date = '14-06-2016';

//convert to standard date format like YYYY-MM-DD
start_date = 
  start_date.split('-')[2]+"-"+start_date.split('-')[1]+"-"+start_date.split('-')[0]

end_date = 
  end_date.split('-')[2]+"-"+end_date.split('-')[1]+"-"+end_date.split('-')[0]

if (Date.parse(start_date) > Date.parse(end_date))
{
    error = true;
    console.log('start date is greater than end date');
}
else
{
    console.log('start date is smaller than end date');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also hide previous datesfrom selected date through javascript.

HTML :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" media="all"><label for="from">From</label> <input type="text" id="from" name="from"/> <label for="to">to</label> <input type="text" id="to" name="to"/>
```

Javascript:

```
var dateToday = new Date(); var dates = $("#from, #to").datepicker({
defaultDate: "+1w",
changeMonth: true,
numberOfMonths: 3,
minDate: dateToday,
onSelect: function(selectedDate) {
    var option = this.id == "from" ? "minDate" : "maxDate",
        instance = $(this).data("datepicker"),
        date = $.datepicker.parseDate(instance.settings.dateFormat || $.datepicker._defaults.dateFormat, selectedDate, instance.settings);
    dates.not(this).datepicker("option", option, date);
}   });
```

Here is a working [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nicolapeluchetti/dAyzq/1/)